# Eclipse finds syntax errors that did not previously exist

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, syntax-error

I have been working on this project for a long time off and on, and just came back to work on it after leaving it for a month.  The last time I worked on it, everything worked fine and I was cleaning stuff up for it to be finished.  Today when I opened eclipse there were numerous errors with no solutions, most of them relating to brackets, but a few of them relating to the actionPerformed method.  I pointed out which lines the errors are on if that helps.  Just wondering if anyone could tell me whether there are real errors or there is something wrong with eclipse.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton rock;
JButton scissors;
JButton paper;
JLabel left;
ImageIcon rock1;
ImageIcon scissors1;
ImageIcon scissors2;
ImageIcon paper2;
ImageIcon paper1;
ImageIcon rock2;
ImageIcon back;
ImageIcon scissorsb;
ImageIcon youWin;
ImageIcon youLose;
ImageIcon Loading;
JLabel background;
JLabel right;
String [] Rock3 = {};
String [] RPS = {"Rock","Paper","Scissors"};
Random rand = new Random ();
Random Prize = new Random ();
int num = rand.nextInt(RPS.length);
int yourChoice = -1;
JLabel winner;
Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
String Tie = "Tie";
String compwins = "Computer wins!";
String youwin = "You win!";
Font winnerFont = new Font("Font", Font.PLAIN, 35);
int yourScore = 0;
int compScore = 0;
String yourNum = Integer.toString(yourScore);
String compNum = Integer.toString(compScore);
JLabel yourPoints = new JLabel();
JLabel compPoints;
private Timer t;
private Timer t2;
private Timer t3;

public  main (){
    super("Rock Paper Scissors");
    back = new ImageIcon("space-wallpaper-space-32897775-1920-1080.jpg");
    youWin = new ImageIcon("you win.png");
    youLose = new ImageIcon("you lose.png");
    paper1 = new ImageIcon("paper1.png");
    paper2 = new ImageIcon("paper2.png");
    scissors1 = new ImageIcon("scissors1.png");
    scissors2 = new ImageIcon("scissors2.png");
    rock1 = new ImageIcon("rock1.png");
    rock2 = new ImageIcon("rock2.png");
    Loading = new ImageIcon("loadingbig.png");

    background = new JLabel();
    left = new JLabel();
    right = new JLabel();
    winner = new JLabel();
    compPoints = new JLabel();
    yourPoints = new JLabel();
    right.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(1920,1080);
    winner.setFont(winnerFont);
    winner.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );

    contentPane.add(compPoints);
    contentPane.add(yourPoints);


        contentPane.setLayout(layout);

        contentPane.add(winner);

        contentPane.add(left);
        contentPane.add(right);



 rock = new JButton("Rock");
 paper = new JButton ("Paper");
 scissors = new JButton ("Scissors");

layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rock,
        500,
        SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
this.add(rock, BorderLayout.NORTH);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, rock,
        -30,
        SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rock,
        40,
        SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
this.add(paper, BorderLayout.NORTH);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, paper,
        -30,
        SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, paper,
        200,
        SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
this.add(scissors, BorderLayout.NORTH);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, scissors,
        -30,
        SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, scissors,
        360,
        SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
rock.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
rock.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,50));
paper.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
paper.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,50));
scissors.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
scissors.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,50));
rock.repaint();
scissors.repaint();
paper.repaint();
Background();


}


public static void main(String args[]){
main framer = new main();
}
@Override
/*Error Here*/public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(arg0.getSource() ==rock){
        left.setIcon(rock1);
        yourChoice = 0;
    }else if(arg0.getSource() ==paper){
        left.setIcon(paper1);
        yourChoice = 1;
    }else if(arg0.getSource() ==scissors){
        left.setIcon(scissors1);
        yourChoice = 2;
    }

    computerMove();


        Score();
        winner();
}
public void Background(){
rock.setVisible(false);
scissors.setVisible(false);
paper.setVisible(false);
contentPane.add(background);
background.setIcon(Loading);
t = new Timer(4000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        background.setIcon(back);
        rock.setVisible(true);
        scissors.setVisible(true);
        paper.setVisible(true);
    }
});
t.setRepeats(false);
t.start();
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
rock.doClick();
paper.doClick();
scissors.doClick();
rock.addActionListener(this);
paper.addActionListener(this);
scissors.addActionListener(this);
}
public void Score(){

yourPoints.setFont(winnerFont);
compPoints.setFont(winnerFont);

layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, yourPoints,
        100,
        SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, yourPoints,
        800,
        SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, compPoints,
        1790,
        SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, compPoints,
        800,
        SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);



if ((num==0 && yourChoice ==0)||(num==2 && yourChoice ==2)||(num==1 && yourChoice   ==1)){
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, winner,
            50,
            SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, winner,
            890,
            SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
    winner.setText(Tie);
    winner.repaint();
    t = new Timer(1400, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            winner.setText(null);
        }   
    });
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();
}else if((num==0 && yourChoice ==2)||(num==2 && yourChoice ==1)||(num==1 && yourChoice   ==0)){
    compScore ++;
    compPoints.setText(compNum);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, winner,
            50,
            SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, winner,
            810,
            SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
    winner.setText(compwins);
    winner.repaint();
    compPoints.repaint();
    /*Error Here*/t2 = new Timer(1400, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        /*Error Here*/public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            winner.setText(null);
            /*Error Here*/} 
        /*Error Here*/});
    t2.setRepeats(false);
    t2.start();
    /*Error Here*/}else if((num==2 && yourChoice ==0)||(num==0 && yourChoice ==1)||(num==1            && yourChoice ==2)){
    yourScore ++;
    yourPoints.setText(yourNum);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, winner,
            50,
            SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, winner,
            850,
            SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
    winner.setText(youwin);
    winner.repaint();
    yourPoints.repaint();
    t3 = new Timer(1400, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            winner.setText(null);
        }
    });
    t3.setRepeats(false);
    /*Error Here*/t3.start();


    /*Error Here*/}
yourNum = Integer.toString(yourScore);
compNum = Integer.toString(compScore);
yourPoints.setText(yourNum);
compPoints.setText(compNum);
winner.repaint();
yourPoints.repaint();
compPoints.repaint();
winner.setForeground(Color.RED);
yourPoints.setForeground(Color.RED);
compPoints.setForeground(Color.RED);




/*Error Here*/}

public void winner(){
if(yourScore == 10){
    background.setIcon(youWin);
    contentPane.add(background);
    background.repaint();
    left.setVisible(false);
    right.setVisible(false);
    yourPoints.setVisible(false);
    compPoints.setVisible(false);
    winner.setVisible(false);
    rock.setVisible(false);
    paper.setVisible(false);
    scissors.setVisible(false);
    t = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            computerMove();
            Score();
            winner();
        }   
    });
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();

}else if(compScore == 10){
background.setIcon(youLose);
contentPane.add(background);
background.repaint();
left.setVisible(false);
right.setVisible(false);
yourPoints.setVisible(false);
compPoints.setVisible(false);
winner.setVisible(false);
rock.setVisible(false);
paper.setVisible(false);
scissors.setVisible(false);
/*Error Here*/t = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    /*Error Here*/public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        computerMove();
        Score();
        winner();
    }   
    /*Error Here*/});
t.setRepeats(false);
t.start();
}
}
public void computerMove(){
 num = rand.nextInt(RPS.length);
if (num==0){
    right.setIcon(rock2);
}else if(num==1){
    right.setIcon(paper2);
}else if(num==2){
    right.setIcon(scissors2);
}


/*Error Here*/}
```

Comment: Did you try clean-build the project again ?

Comment: There are lots of errors starting with duplicate method definition.

Comment: Holy indentation! I've had this happen to me before and I just refreshed the project.  Try exiting eclipse too, if that doesn't work.  clean-build like suggested above could also help.

Comment: Naming your class "main" is a really bad idea. At least make it Main with an upper case M. Your public main() did confuse me at first.

Comment: thanks everyone, I'll try these things and get back to you

Comment: None of these methods have worked :(

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're facing weird issues with eclipse, try to do the following:

- Clean the project. `Project` --> `Clean...`.
- Close the project and reopen it again. `Project` --> `Open Project`/`Close Project`.
- Make a copy of the source file and delete the original file, then paste the source file again.

Comment: I'll try that out and tell you what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing brace for `computerMove`.

When solving problems like this, try commenting out methods until you get something that compiles, then uncomment small blocks of code until you find the offending block.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a closing bracket `}` at the end of the file.

Pretty bad indentation and naming makes it hard to notice. Take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that, I feel like an idiot.  As to the formatting, this was my first project and I'm too lazy to fix it now.

Comment: @TheFloatingLlama: Ctrl+Shift+F or right click: Source->Format. Or Ctrl+A then Ctrl+I (Source->Correct Indentation) shouldn't take that much effort ;-)